# Could someone go through this Python code and explain it to me

Tags: python

```
months = ['January',
          'February',
          'March',
          'April',
          'May',
          'June',
          'July',
          'August',
          'September',
          'October',
          'November',
          'December']

def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        cap_month = month.capitalize()
        if cap_month in months:
            return cap_month
```

so above is python code that creates a list of months and basically prints what the user enters if it's valid month or not. the above code is nice.

below is another version similar to the above but I guess better or more user-friendly. but I'm not sure how this works exactly I haven't seen python dictionaries in this manner could someone go through this code and explain it to me thanks a lot I appreciate.

```
months_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(), m) for m in months)

def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        short_month = month[:3].lower()
        return month_abbvs.get(short_month)
```

Comment: in first code , months is a list not a dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help to print out what you get from that extra step:

```
>>> months_abbvs
{'apr': 'April',
 'aug': 'August',
 'dec': 'December',
 'feb': 'February',
 'jan': 'January',
 'jul': 'July',
 'jun': 'June',
 'mar': 'March',
 'may': 'May',
 'nov': 'November',
 'oct': 'October',
 'sep': 'September'}
```

So, you have a mapping of lowercased abbreviations to full month names.

How does that work? Well, first, let's look at what the expression does:

```
>>> m = 'December'
>>> m[:3].lower()
'dec'
>>> m[:3].lower(), m
('dec', 'December')
```

---

So, the comprehension just does that for each month:

```
>>> [(m[:3].lower(), m) for m in months]
[('jan', 'January'),
 ('feb', 'February'),
 ('mar', 'March'),
 ('apr', 'April'),
 ('may', 'May'),
 ('jun', 'June'),
 ('jul', 'July'),
 ('aug', 'August'),
 ('sep', 'September'),
 ('oct', 'October'),
 ('nov', 'November'),
 ('dec', 'December')]
```

As explained in more detail in [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), a comprehension is basically shorthand for a loop. In particular, this:

```
>>> m2 = [<expression with m> for m in months]
```

… is equivalent to:

```
>>> m2 = []
>>> for m in months:
...     m2.append(<expression with m>)
```

---

Using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension just means the sequence is built as a lazy iterator instead of a list.

And then passing the result (either way) to `dict` builds a dictionary mapping the first value of each tuple to the second.

---

You could write this all a bit more readably as a dictionary comprehension:

```
months_abbvs = {m[:3].lower(): m for m in months}
```

Even better, instead of writing `m[:3].lower()` repeatedly, give it a nice name and use that:

```
def abbreviate(m):
    return m[:3].lower()
months_abbvs = {abbreviate(m): m for m in months}
```

And then:

```
def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        short_month = abbreviate(month)
        return month_abbvs.get(short_month)
```

---

Now, what you do with your input in the new version is:

```
short_month = month[:3].lower()
return month_abbvs.get(short_month)
```

Since `month_abbvs` is a `dict` (you can tell that by printing it out, or just from the fact that it was created by calling `dict` on something), the `get` method is [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). So, as explained in the linked docs, `month_abbvs.get(short_month)` is the same as `months_abbvs[short_month]`, except that if the key `short_month` is not found, you will get `None`, instead of raising an exception.

So, if given `'October'`, you'll set `short_month` to `'oct'`. And then you look it up in the abbreviation dictionary, which returns `'October'`. If given `'OCT'` or `'october'` or `'octal digit string'`, you'll also return the same thing. Since any non-empty string is truthy, if you've done something like `if valid_month('October'):`, it will be true.

But, if given, say, `'Muhammed'`, you'll set `short_month` to `'muh'`. And then you look that up, and it isn't there. As explained above, the `get` method returns `None` for unknown keys, so you will return `None`. Since `None` is falsey, if you've done something like `if valid_month('Muhammed'):`, it will not be true.

In other words, it makes the function more lenient—which may be an improvement, or may be a bad thing (or may be a little of both—maybe you wanted `'OCT'` to work, but not `'octal digit string'`).

Comment: wheres does the get method come from in month_abbvs.get(short_month)

Comment: also could you briefly explain the whole comprehension concept not familiar with fully on how it works here

Comment: @muhammed: I'll edit the answer to explain a bit, and add some links. And thanks for clarifying the parts you needed explained.

Answer (score 2):

```
months_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(), m) for m in months)
# months_abbvs = { 'jan':'January', 'feb':'February',... }
# the actual operation is two-step:
#     1. [(m[:3].lower(),m) for m in months] list comprehension over the "months" list which:
#     1.1. [m[:3].lower()] take first three letters of each item in the list, apply lowercase()
#     1.2. [(m[:3].lower,m)] return a tuple of (1.1, item)
#     2. [dict(...)] build a dictionary from the list comprehension
#     2.2. for each tuple returned from (1.2), create a key:value pair in the dict

def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        short_month = month[:3].lower()
        # get first three letters as lowercase string
        return month_abbvs.get(short_month)
        # 1. [month_abbvs.get(short_month)] perform dict.get(key)
        # 2. return result of 1 (None if no such key exists)
```

The reason this is more efficient is that `dict` uses a hashset for its internal representation, so finding whether a key exists in it or not is an (amortized) O(1) operation, whereas doing the same over a list is a worst-case-scenario O(n) operation for a list of size n.

As per @abarnert's comment, this also makes it more user-friendly to code, as you get away with simply doing a `dict.get(key)` and not worrying about iteration logic in your code. The condition becomes a "True/False" question, rather than a "Is it True for either of the cases in this set [...]?"

Comment: I don't think that efficiency is relevant here. The change is a major change to the semantics of the function, and the point was apparently to make it "more user-friendly", so the semantics, rather than the performance, are what matters.

Comment: Also, if performance were what mattered here, it would be a lot simpler—and a little faster, too—to just change `months` into a `set` by replacing the square brackets with curly braces, and leave everything else unchanged.

Comment: @abarnert agreed. I'm guessing the code in the question is from some online course...  I also guessed (maybe incorrectly?) that the question was asking "what is happening in this code?" rather than why, hence the breakdown in the code section. It's rough, but I think it describes the process itself accurately.

Comment: Your new edit says "you get away with simply doing a `dict.get(key)` and not worrying about iteration logic"… but his original version didn't worry about iteration logic either; it just did a `cap_month in months` check. So, that comment is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The other two questions explain in detail how the code works, but I'd like to draw your attention to one particular facet of how the code is designed: it has tests to avoid exceptions, and if those tests fail, the code stops executing, such that execution falls off the end of the function text, and returns `None`.

A simpler way to write the code is to eliminate the checks, and handle the exceptions:

```
def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        # this will raise an exception if month is not a string
        short_month = month[:3].lower() 
        return month_abbvs.get(short_month)
```

becomes:

```
def valid_month(month):
    try:
        return month_abbvs.get(month[:3].lower())
    except KeyError, AttributeError: # or Exception to catch everything
        return None
```

Which gives us one main line to comprehend, which is a bit easier in this case. Obviously, the more checks, the more simplicity this gives us.

---

```
def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        cap_month = month.capitalize()
        if cap_month in months:
            return cap_month
```

becomes:

```
def valid_month(month):
    try:
        cap_month = month.capitalize()
        if cap_month and cap_month in months:
            return cap_month
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

Which doesn't buy us very much in this case. It's good to be able to employ both styles.

Comment: Thanks this is actually very helpful.

Comment: This isn't right. `month_abbvs.get(…)` will never raise a `KeyError`. And nothing will raise an `AttributeError` unless `month` is not a sequence, which is not at all the same test as `if month:`, which tests for (among other things) an empty string.

Comment: @abarnert try `month=['foo'];month.capitalize()` and tell me what you get.

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, in addition to skipping some of the tests he used to do, you've also added tests for completely _different_ problems that his original code didn't test for.